# Is there any function available to transfer the flow in c++ programming alternative to while or do while loop?

Tags: c++, control-flow

I am new to programming. & generally used to do programming on weekends. While working on a mini ATM project the problem arrives when i need to transfer the flow of the program back to up to the first line. i have already written the code of 1256 line so i can't re-structured it for while or do while loop.I searched for it a lot in the online portals but couldn't found a satisfactory results. My question is that is there any in-build function or way available for that cause.

my first line was.`std::cout<<"Wlcome to your account \n";`
Then my selecting option.
`std::cout<<"press 12 to go to main manue \n";`
that was my else if statement from where i want to send back my flow towards the first line.
 `else if (in.amount==12) { }`

what could i write in that brackets to send back the flow of program to first line and the screen show's me agian "Welcome to your account"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i have already written the code of 1256 line so i can't re-structured it for while or do while loop.

Why not? You could just wrap a `while` loop around the whole thing.

That said, there is a way to do exactly what you're asking for: `goto`.

First you need to label one of your statements. For example:

```
int main() {
  the_beginning:
    std::cout << "Welcome to your account\n";
    ...
}
```

Then you can do `goto the_beginning;` to transfer control to the statement labeled `the_beginning`.

See [`goto` on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto) for more information and examples.

Comment: I've heard that `goto` is bad practice in your programs and makes it into spaghetti code. I just wanted to know how would you exit the label.

Comment: @Rahul You cannot "enter" a label, so what do you mean by "exit"?

Comment: Both suggestions certainly solve the specific problem being descripbed, however, it should be pointed out that this issue reveals that the overall code is most probably a big mess; if @ahmadraza is learning by himself or if it's a homework assignment, I recommend that he tries to learn a bit more about how to structure his code.

Comment: Basically how would you loop out of this?

Comment: @Rahul It's not a loop, so there is no "out".

Comment: @melpomene i think goto is more preferable to solve that problem

Comment: @melpomene is it implicit that `goto label` would be inside a condition? Other wise it would keep going to that label forever. I feel dumb.

Comment: @Rahul Make an exit label out of the loop and an `if` statement with a `goto`.

Comment: @Rahul In OP's code, yes: "*`else if (in.amount==12) { }` what could i write in that brackets to send back the flow of program to first line*". In general, no; but you could use another `goto` to transfer control somewhere else, or `return` out of the function, or `throw`, or `setjmp`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `goto` (which is a very bad practice in a high-level language). You can simply wrap your whole function in an infinite loop:

You had:

```
void foo()
{
  // code
  // you want to restart here
  // you want to quit here
  // code
}
```

You will have:

```
void foo()
{
  for(;;)
  {
    // code

    // you want to restart here
    continue;

    // you want to quit here
    break;

    // code

    break; // if you want to terminate at the end;
  }
}
```

Comment: "Very bad" - no, not really. Just usually has better structured alternatives. And still, some tasks are *better* with goto than without.

Comment: @StoryTeller How did you determine that they are "better" with `goto`? Did you try debugging a code with such structure? Are you talking about optimising an exit from multiple loops or exit from a loop from within a `switch` statement?

Comment: I determined it by thinking for myself instead of regurgitating the title of Dijkstra's famous article. Resource cleanup in function's reads *better*, is localized, and is DRYer than when hacks are used to avoid goto. Heck, even under the analysis Dijkstra presents in his paper such code stands very well. Other examples include certain state machine algorithms. The key is code *structure*, not avoidance of goto. That's what even the paper is about.

Comment: @StoryTeller So you have not tried debugging a code like that. It shows. To the question poster: There are times when `goto` is a good idea, but it is quite rare. It is akin to security through obscurity, sometimes it is needed. Sometimes you need blinking text on a website. Sometimes you need a double negative in your switches. But if you are designing the system it is significantly better if you thread on the side of avoiding these things, and only put them in after having thought about the consequences, and "sticking it to Dijkstra" is not "thinking about the consequences".

Comment: The only thing that shows is your zealotry. I've debugged terrible code with goto, and terrible code without goto. What both had in common is owners that used boogeyman "consequences" and "you clearly haven't done this or that" as arguments to stifle discussion.

Comment: @StoryTeller [and "you clearly haven't done this or that" as arguments to stifle discussion] oh the irony (cough) [instead of regurgitating the title of Dijkstra's famous article] (cough)

Comment: Careful, we wouldn't want you to choke.

Comment: @v010dya (to your answer) not if OP's code has that *`else`*  (deeply) *nested*. or if it has several "entry" points to return to (to "restart" at).